# Send mouse click to process

Tags: c#, process, mouseevent, message, send

I'm trying to accomplish sending a mouse click to a application.

I currently have:

```
    int hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Window Title Here");
            SendMessage(hwnd, 0x201, 0, 0); //Mouse left down
            SendMessage(hwnd, 0x202, 0, 0); //Mouse left up
```

I'm using

```
     [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

and

```
    [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(String ClassName, String WindowName);
```

But I get errors, these are:

"The name 'hwnd' does not exist in the current context"

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

C# is case-sensitive. `hwnd` and `hWnd` are different things.

Comment: I just changed hwnd to hWnd, now I get this error:
"The best overloaded method match for 'Cross_Click.Form1.SendMessage(System.IntPtr, int, int, int)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'Cross_Click.Form1.SendMessage(System.IntPtr, int, int, int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Possibly because `IntPtr` is not the same as `int`?

Comment: With IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Window Title Here"); I get 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.IntPtr'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: And, _are_ you missing a cast? Are you missing the documentation on the [IntPtr structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19665/discussion-between-layne-wapp-and-john-saunders)

Comment: I use 
 IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "iw5mp.exe");
                PostMessage(hWnd, 0x201, 0, 0); //Mouse left down
              PostMessage(hWnd, 0x202, 0, 0); //Mouse left up
and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

There's already libraries doing that, `Windows Input Simulator` would be an example, if you can use it, it would save you from having to write this kind of code. See on [CodePlex](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I use this
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "iw5mp.exe");
                PostMessage(hWnd, 0x201, 0, 0); //Mouse left down
              PostMessage(hWnd, 0x202, 0, 0); //Mouse left up

and when I put that in a timer nothing happens. Why?